# My betta is laying as the bottom of the tank with its head pointed up, why?

Tags: behavior, aquarium, fish, betta

My fish lines in a 2.5 galling tank with a automatic heater and a thermometer. I got it yesterday (after my first one who lived for 2.5 years lived there) I cleaned it thoroughly and made sure no traces were left (of salt used to clean it). My other fish swam around a lot when I first got it but this one just lays with its head pointed up. I do weekly 100% water changes with tap water + conditioner + aquarium salt and feed it bloodworms and pellets, it also does not eat the food. It looks like the water is pushing him down, he is struggling to get up. What am I doing wrong?

[image][image][image]

Comment: Well I am not an expert in fishes but my common sense tell me that you might want to try to change to another kind of water (to see how your fish reacts), perhaps the aquarium salt is affecting your fish.

Comment: Aquarium salt should not be used unless you are treating a sick fish. Too much salt can actually burn and cause discomfort for the fish. Additionally, I wouldn’t do full 100% water changes as this can remove all the good bacteria along with the bad bacteria. Those might be good places to start